# "mvn package" failure altough in Eclipse this maven web application runs

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I got this error after doing "mvn clean package":

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1:w
>   ar (default-war) on project webapp1:
>   Error assembling WAR: webxml attribute
>   is re quired (or pre-existing
>   WEB-INF/web.xml if executing in update
>   mode) -> [Help 1]

altough this maven web application runs smoothly via Eclipse (Run As / Run on Server).

Comment: Do you have WEB-INF folder under src/main/webapp? Does it have the web.xml file?

Comment: Also take a look at this relevant JIRA http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR-53. What version of war plugin are you using?

Answer (score 9):

By default `maven-war-plugin` expects webapp files to be in `${baseDir}/src/main/webapp` folder. In your case these files can be located in another folder (Eclipse's Dynamic Web Project uses `${baseDir}/WebContent`). If so, you need to move these files into default folder (it may require additional Eclipse configuration) or configure `warSourceDirectory` option of `maven-war-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: when I added <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory> (with $baseDir was the same error) maven build was successed but in .war files there were no .class and .properties files from src folder (libraries and content of WebContent folder were in .war)

Comment: @j2j: Perhaps other folders don't match Maven default layout as well, so you need to configure source and resource folders too (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build_Element).